# redirect_uri mismatch error django heroku app

Tags: django, heroku, oauth-2.0, django-allauth

After deploying a Django google single sign-in app on Heroku I am facing redirect_uri mismatch although I have the correct redirect URI in the google credentials. I don't know where the problem is occurring. The same thing is working perfectly in the local machine. Please help.

Comment: check whether your redirct uri is same like this ``http://localhost.com:8000/accounts/social/google/login/callback/`` or ``http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/social/google/login/callback/``

Comment: Vanshika, I think you didn't provide enough information for others to be able to spot the problem. It would be good to mention what you have already tried, some configuration values (at least the redirect URI) and other details that could help solving the problem - maybe some Heroku settings (but I know nothing about it).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: did you fix it? have a similar issue using `heroku` and `django all auth`, works on my machine(not development server but heroku’s) but anyone who tries to login on another machine gets a `redirect uri mismatch error`.